# GCD of many numbers divisible by another number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

$a$ is an integer such that:

$$a \mid \gcd(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_z)$$

and $z$ can be very large.

Does the GCD approach $a$ as $z$ grows? If yes, what is the relation between $z$ and $a$?

Thanks...

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without knowing something about the $b_i$. (Also, the word _approach_ is inappropriate for a sequence of integers; either the GCD is eventually _equal_ to $a$ for large enough $z$, or it isn't. But we can't tell which, without more information.)

Comment: Thanks. the $bs$ are unique... not sure what other information you need ?

Comment: The GCD might approach any multiple of $a$ as $z$ grows.

Answer (score 1):

Using the constant sequence
$b_n=2$ for all $n$, and choosing $a=1$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
a&\mid \gcd(b_1) & 1 &\mid 2 & \checkmark\\\\
a&\mid \gcd(b_1,b_2) & 1 &\mid 2 & \checkmark\\\\
a&\mid \gcd(b_1,b_2,b_3) & 1 &\mid 2 & \checkmark\\\\
&&\Large\vdots
\end{align*}$$
but $\gcd(b_1,\ldots,b_z)=2$ for any choice of $z$, and does not approach $a=1$.

Comment: Thanks. In other cases where $a<>1$. does having $z$ approach infinity have any relation to $a$?

Comment: If you don't want $a=1$, then let $b_n=4$ for every $n$, and let $a=2$, and you'll have the same problem.

Comment: $b_n$ are unique.... any difference?

Comment: If you want $b_n$ to be unique, then let $b_n=4^n$ for every $n$, and let $a=2$, and you'll have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I'm about to answer a *different* question, but perhaps you had something similar in mind. Might be overkill, but here I go.

---

In the statement of your question, you seem to understand that by taking bigger and bigger *samples* of the $b_i$, all of them divisible by $a$, it must be the case that “in the limit, $\gcd(b_1,\dots,b_z)$ must approach $a$”.

In the following I'll only discuss the case $a=1$; I'm leaving the general case as an “exercise for the reader”.

It was made clear in comments and in @ZevChonoles answer that a straightforward interpretation of this does not make sense, specially since the integers are **discrete** (as opposed to the real numbers, where you may approach indefinitely some number). But we may ask

> (1) which is the *probability* that $z$ integers taken “at random“ have $\gcd$ equal to $1$ (here the requirement that $a$ divide each $b_i$ trivializes).

Even defining how two integers are “taken at random” must be done carefully; in this case, we say that  the probability that a natural  number $n$ satisfies  a property $P(n)$ is taken to be the limit of the quotient
$$
\frac{\# \{n \in \mathbb{N}: n \leq N \text{ and } P(n)\}}{\#   \{n \in \mathbb{N}: n \leq N \}}
$$
as $N$ approaches infinity (whenever this limit exists).

Back to question (1), the case $z=2$ is a classical problem, and it has been addressed in other questions, for example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64498/probability-that-two-random-numbers-are-coprime). The answer is $\frac{1}{\zeta(2)} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$, where $\zeta$ is [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). Now I'll rephrase your question in the following way:

> (2) Take $z$ integers $b_1,\dots,b_z$ at random, all of them divisible by $a$. Then the limit of the probability that $\gcd(b_1,\dots,b_z) = a$ as $z\to\infty$, is $1$.

Recall I'm working under the assumption $a=1$. So we're interested in knowing the probability that $z$ integers are coprime. Now [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Probabilities) states a generalization of the result we quoted for $z=2$: This probability is $\frac{1}{\zeta(z)}$. Now, it can be seen that $\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{1}{\zeta(z)}=1$. This shows that the interpretation of your question given by (2) is indeed true.

Comment: Great Pedro... question # 2 only applies to $a=1$. My original question was intended to see if $a$ is unknown, and I have z integers that are divisible by $a$, could I solve for $a$ if $z\to\infty$. Thanks

Comment: @orcking I didn't think about it, but it is likely that the same argument will work for the general case.