# Probability of a fraction $a/b$ that cannot be simplified

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a$ and $b$ be random integers chosen independently from the uniform distribution on $\{1, 2,\dotsc, N\}$. As $N \rightarrow \infty$, what is the probability that the fraction:

$$\frac{a}{b}$$

cannot be simplified?

Note: As specified in the comments, the question is the same as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64498/probability-that-two-random-numbers-are-coprime-is-frac6-pi2).

Comment: That's equal to the probability that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Since prime numbers follow a $\log$ distribution, I _think_ that the probability must be zero in the end.

Comment: There is no uniform distribution on positive integers.  What is true is that if $a$ and $b$ are chosen independently from the uniform distribution on $\{1,2,\ldots, N\}$, then asymptotically as $N \to \infty$ the probability approaches $6/\pi^2$.

Comment: Here is a video of a mathematician doing this very problem with dice and explaining the maths: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZBhSi_PwHU

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64498/probability-that-two-random-numbers-are-coprime-is-frac6-pi2

Comment: This question does not meet the standards of Math SE.  It is both lacking context, and is a duplicate of another question.  However, I think that the underlying question is interesting, and that Eevee Trainer's answer is worth keeping on the site.  I have, therefore, closed the question as a duplicate and locked it.  For further discussion, I would invite those involved to chat in [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56205616#56205616).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Peter's answer gets to the heart of the matter relatively quickly, but I feel it would also be best to demonstrate where the $6/\pi^2$ comes from, seemingly out of nowhere to the uninitiated.

So, it should be obvious that $a/b$ is in simplest form if and only if $a,b$ are coprime, i.e. $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. Well, what does that mean? It means that $a,b$ share no common prime number factors.

In particular, it means $a,b$ do not share a factor of $2$. For (uniformly randomly chosen) nonzero integers $a,b$ (less than some other number $x$), there is a $1/2$ chance (in the limit $x \to \infty$) each will have a factor of $2$. Thus,

$$P(\text{a,b do not have a mutual factor of 2}) = 1 - \left(\frac 1 2 \right)^2$$

Similarly, it means that they do not share a factor of $3$. There's a $1/3$ chance each will have a factor of three, and thus,

$$P(\text{a,b do not have a mutual factor of 3}) = 1 - \left(\frac 1 3 \right)^2$$

This clearly generalizes. Consider a prime number $p$. There is a $1/p$ chance that $a,b$ each will have it, and in turn

$$P(\text{a,b do not have a mutual factor of p}) = 1 - \left(\frac 1 p \right)^2$$

For $a,b$ to be coprime this needs to be true of **all** primes $p$. The events are independent, and we accordingly can multiply the respective probabilities for each prime $p$, obtaining

$$P(\text{a,b are coprime}) = \prod_{\text{p prime}} 1 - \left(\frac 1 p \right)^2 = \prod_{\text{p prime}} 1 -  \frac 1 {p^2}$$

This now ties into something known as the Riemann zeta function. There are two formulas typically associated with it: a summation and a product formula. We often focus on the summation formula but can derive the latter; a proof of said derivation can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function). In any event, we focus on the prime product formula below:

$$\zeta(s) = \prod_{\text{p prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$$

Bearing in mind this is a product, we can do a manipulation:

$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \prod_{\text{p prime}} 1-\frac 1 {p^{s}}$$

This looks precisely like the formula for our probability of $a,b$ being coprime but with $s$ in lieu of $2$. Indeed, letting $s=2$,

$$P(\text{a,b are coprime}) = \prod_{\text{p prime}} 1 - \frac{1}{p^2} = \frac{1}{\zeta(2)}$$

$\zeta(2)$ is a known value which Euler calculated to be $\pi^2/6$; finding this value is often referred to as the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem). Accordingly,

$$P(\text{a,b are coprime}) = \frac{1}{\pi^2/6} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$$

The idea also generalizes further. Say you have some group of $n$ integers ($n$ a positive integer). Then the probability that all $n$ are coprime is given by

$$P(\text{all n numbers are coprime}) = \frac{1}{\zeta(n)}$$

Comment: This same heuristic can be applied to finding the probability that an integer is "$k$-free" (that is, an integer having no perfect $k$th power factor > 1), which also happens to be $\frac{1}{\zeta\left(k\right)}.$ In fact, the probability that greatest common divisor of $n$ integers has no perfect $k$th power factor > 1 (that is, the probability of $n$ integers being relatively $k$-prime) is $\frac{1}{\zeta\left(nk\right)}.$

Answer (score 4):

This question is equivalent to ask for the probability that $a$ and $b$ are coprime. If $a$ and $b$ are random integers below $x$, then the probability $P(x)$ that $a$ and $b$ are coprime , satisfies $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} P(x)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\approx0.6079$$