# Find the asympt. expan. as $N \rightarrow \infty$ of $\sum_{r,s,t=1}^{N} \left[\sqrt{s^2 \pm 4 r t} \in \mathbb{Z}\right] \left[\gcd(r,s,t)=1\right]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, asymptotics, quadratics, gcd-and-lcm

Where $[...]$ are the Iverson brackets.  This expression arises from my research on counting the number of reducible quadratics with coefficients constrained by naive height $N \ge 1$ and $r$, $s$, $t$ are integer coefficients of $r x^2 + s x + t$.  The term $s^2 \pm 4 r t$ is the quadratic discriminant, thus this problem is counting the number of perfect square discriminants.  The $+4 r t$ arises from splitting these sums over $- N \le r, s, t \le + N$ into the domains $1 \le r, s, t \le N$.  I have not made any progress in reducing the title sum or rewriting it in a different form.

The second part of this problem is the reduction of the unconstrained sum $$\sum_{r, s, t=1}^{N} \left[\sqrt{s^2 \pm 4 r t} \in \mathbb{Z}\right]$$ and its corresponding asymptotic expansion as $N \rightarrow \infty$.  The problem that I posted at [Looking for asymp exp as $N \rightarrow \infty$ for $\sum_{r=1}^{N}\sum_{t=1}^{N}\left[\sqrt{rt}\in Z\right]$ w/wo the constraint $GCD(r,t)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473033/looking-for-asymp-exp-as-n-rightarrow-infty-for-sum-r-1n-sum-t-1n) does answer some parts of this problem for the case when $s=0$.

If we sum over the three variables $r$, $s$, and $t$ with $\gcd \left(r,s,t \right)=1$ then we have the probability of three integers chosen at random being coprime is

$$\frac{1}{N^3} \sum_{r,s,t = 1}^{N} \left[\gcd \left(r,s,t \right) = 1 \right] = \frac{1}{N^3} \sum_{d = 1}^{N} \mu \left(d \right) {\left\lfloor{\frac{N}{d}}\right\rfloor}^{3} \sim \frac{1}{\zeta \left(3 \right)} + \cdots$$

where $\mu \left(n \right)$ is the Mobius function.

We can write the condition that $\left[{\gcd \left({r, s, t}\right) = 1}\right]$ as

$$\sum_{r, s, t = 1}^{N} \left[{\sqrt{{s}^{2} \pm 4\, r\, t} \in \mathbb{Z}}\right] \left[{\gcd \left({r, s, t}\right) = 1}\right] = \sum_{r, s, t = 1}^{N} \sum_{d \mid \gcd \left({r,s,t}\right)} \left[{\sqrt{{s}^{2} \pm 4\, r\, t} \in \mathbb{Z}}\right] \mu \left({d}\right)$$