# On the coprimeness probability

Tags: number-theory, integers, coprime

we all know that if we pick two random integer numbers, then the probability of them being coprimes is $6/\pi^2$.

But as I have understood that probability is true if we pick a number that goes from $0$ to $\infty$.
What is that probability if we pick a number that goes from $0$ to $N$ where $N$ is an integer positive number ?

Comment: The standard proofs of the claim you start with finite bounds and pass to the limit.  See, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64498/probability-that-two-random-numbers-are-coprime-is-frac6-pi).

Comment: Thanks Lulu, and sorry for my lack of "pro" knowledge. How can I derive a formula that does not pass to the limit ? A formula that involves the term N , for example ?

Comment: The link i provided has formulas for a finite bound (they use $x$ instead of $N$ to denote the bound).  the exact formulas are, of course, a bit hard to work with but the asymptotic formulas are good.