# Roll a die, win a $\pi$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, pi

Define $k$ (number of faces on the fair die) and T (number of trials).

Roll it twice and record the outcomes as $x,y \in {1,2,\dots,k}$.

Let $C$ count the number of times that $GCD(x,y)=1$ after $T$ trials.

The probability of being coprime (i.e., $GCD =1)$ is

$$ \frac{C}{T} $$

However, the [Probability that two random numbers are coprime is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64498/probability-that-two-random-numbers-are-coprime-is-frac6-pi2)

So,

$$\frac{6}{\pi^2} = \frac{C}{T}$$

Thus, an estimate of $\pi$ is

$$\pi \approx \sqrt{\frac{6T}{C}}$$

Wrote a [C program](https://godbolt.org/z/vGPs4EYc7) to estimate $\pi$ using $10,000,000$ for the faces and trials to improve accuracy. (Approx pi value: $3.141503$)

Is this a valid method to calculate happy $\pi$ day?

Comment: No - it will almost certainly head to the wrong limit with a $6$-sided die, no matter how many times you roll it.  The statement about $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ is the limit as the number of sides increases towards infinity (as well as the number of rolls)

Comment: There are some other monte carlo pi ideas [here](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/estimating-%CF%80-using-monte-carlo-simulations-3459a84b5ef9)

Comment: @Henry I think the OP means that the die will have 10,000,000 faces and there'll be 10,000,000 rolls.

Comment: @A.J. Fair enough though I doubt it is accurate to more than about 3 decimal places

Comment: @Henry I think you're right about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an approximation to two distinct limits, one as the number of faces increases (with six-sided dice you might think about $\sqrt{6 \times \frac{36}{23}} \approx 3.0645$) and the other from simulation in a law of large numbers sense as the number of rolls increases.

So you will only get an approximation.  C would be faster, but in R you might do something like

```
set.seed(2023)
faces <- 10^7
rolls <- 10^7
firstroll  <- sample(faces, rolls, replace=TRUE)
secondroll <- sample(faces, rolls, replace=TRUE)
higher <- ifelse(firstroll > secondroll, firstroll, secondroll)
lower  <- firstroll + secondroll - higher
hcf <- numeric(0)
while (length(lower) > 0){ 
   remainder <- higher %% lower
   hcf <- c(hcf, lower[remainder == 0])
   higher <- lower[remainder > 0]
   lower  <- remainder[remainder > 0]
   }
mean(hcf == 1)                   # 6/pi^2 = 0.60792710
# 0.6080553
sqrt(6 * rolls / sum(hcf == 1))  #     pi = 3.14159265
# 3.141261
```

which is not awful, but if you are going to use a computer then there are better and faster ways to get a good estimate of $\pi$.